# IE and Safari allowing cookies in IFrame

Tags: php, html, iframe

I am trying to load a webpage inside an IFrame. The problem is that the page requires cookies to work correctly. In Firefox and Chrome this works fine however in IE and Safari this does not work as these browsers are blocking cookies in IFrames!

Any ideas?

Comment: is your iframe in a different domain name?

Comment: Yes... Don't use iframes :)  That is generally an archaic approach.  If you need to fetch remote data, perhaps look into using javascript/jQuery methods to do this.

Comment: Hi its for an online meeting software that we are trying to integrate into our own website:- basically an IFrame is the only way to do it!